# Alternative to built-in XmlPullParser with good encoding support

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

I'm porting a project written for BlackBerry (Java) to Android. The project contains some xml parsing classes written against the `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser` interface. the actual parser instance is injected in those classes from outside.

This app parses xml files that are encoded in [ISO-8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso_8859_15) (aka Latin 9). I can't use UTF-8, unfortunately I need to stick to this encoding.

The old BlackBerry project used [kxml2](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/kxml2/) pull parser. Now in android I was trying to use the built-in parser that can be obtained like this:

```
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
```

And then I configure the char encoding:

```
parser.setInput(<input stream>, "ISO-8859-15");
```

The problem is that this parser does not support this char encoding. This is the exception thrown:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Error parsing document. (position:line -1, column -1) caused by: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: unknown encoding.
```

And it's really odd because I know Android supports this encoding. The proof is this line runs with no exceptions:

```
String test  = new String("hi".getBytes(), "ISO-8859-15");
```

However, if I configure the parser for a different encoding, like UTF-8 or latin-1, it works.

Next thing I tried is to use the old project's parser (kxml2) in Android, but then I got new errors:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@9:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43e97088)
```

Even if I could use it without issues, kxml2 hasn't received support in the last years (last version released in 2006), so I'd like to use Android's pull parser if possible, which is more robust and also would have better performance.

I can fool the default parser calling `parser.setInput(bais, "ISO-8859-1");`, because this way it ignores the encoding in the XML declaration in the file, and it works because both charsets have the same number of characters and most of them are the same. But this way someone looking at the source code could think that it uses latin-1 when actually it receives input in latin-9 and hence produces strings in latin-9.

Is there any reason for the default XML Pull Parser for not supporting ISO-8859-15? Is there any alternative PULL parsing library with good char encoding support?

Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE: When I wrote the question I have tested the default parser in OS 2.2 and 2.3. However, reading the javadoc for `Xml.newPullParser` I found this:

> *Note: This is actually slower than the SAX parser, and it's not fully implemented. If you need a fast, mostly implemented pull parser, use this. If you need a complete implementation, use KXML.*

And in fact, when testing the default parser in OS 4.x, I got the second exception. Looks like for OS 4 the built-in parser is actually kxml!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like it's difficult to find a good XmlPullParser library, so I'm going to use kxml's parser following the advice in javadocs for `Xml.newPullParser` factory method. (I've not found this note in the online javadocs, only in eclipse's javadoc window. Maybe I'm using old javadocs and this note was later removed after Android started using kxml as built-in parser).

As for the exception thrown when using kxml's parser, which was this:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@9:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43e97088)
```

It turned out it was caused by my code. In the initial port, I realized that Android's built-in parser included in Froyo and Gingerbread did not advance to next tag after calling `parser.nextText`. So I added some `parser.nexTag` lines here and there to make it work. Then I switched again to kXml but I keep those extra lines, which made my KXmlParser instance to mess up when processing the end of the file. The exception is thrown when calling `nextTag` after having reached the end of the file. This is also explained in the docs for `nextTag`:

> Call next() and return event if it is START_TAG or END_TAG **otherwise throw an exception**.